# How to convert mm/dd/yyy to datetime and save in sql in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, date-format

I am having trouble when converting dates from json in a DateTime value that then I could insert into a database.

The problem comes because json's date format is `mm/dd/yyy` and Trying to convert that value to datetime works until it comes a date like `"07/13/2020"`.

```
fecha = json.created_at;             
date = Convert.ToDateTime(fecha);
string finalDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

So I need to know how can I change format of this value, so then it can always be converted to datetime

Comment: What's the problem with how Convert.ToDateTime() is formatting it?

Comment: I'm doing a loop over a json results, this json returns dates in mm/dd/yyy format, problem comes in    "date = Convert.ToDateTime(fecha);"  when the value returns something like   07/13/2020  since month "13" doesn't exists

Comment: tip: when you want to save a `DateTime` into the database: **don't format it at all**. Use a parameter where the `.Value` is the `DateTime`; then it will be correct; that leaves the parse step - so: perhaps use `DateTime.Parse` and provide a format specifier?

Comment: @victoriana SQL should still recognize that as a date, correct?

Comment: @victoriana `Convert.ToDateTime(fecha)` uses `CurrentCulture` as the `IFormatProvider` by default. That means if your culture is e.g. `en-US` it will try to parse into `MM/dd/yyyy`. As Marc said, if you know what the format will be, use the `DateTime.Parse` method.

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple you can define your json format while converting your json date to datetime

```
 fecha = json.created_at;  //"07/13/2020";
 var date = DateTime.ParseExact(fecha, "MM/dd/yyyy", 
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

 string finalDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8) is the method you are looking for:
`DateTime.ParseExact(fecha, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`
yields [7/13/2020 12:00:00 AM].

Pay attention to capital and small M in the format string, M is month, m is minute!